# Customize edit functionlity

Tags: apex

Hi I am new to salesforce and currently working on one vf page where I need to display organisational details of all the organisation in one vf page. each organisation record has edit and del links. On clicking on the edit link I need to redirect to another vf page which shows the organisation details of the organisation whose edit link I have clicked.
Not Sure how to do this?

Comment: You will probably be able to solve this with lightning components or a visual force page. What have you tried so far, what are specific issues that you're running into?

Comment: Hi so far I just fetched the records of organisation and displayed it on vf page. But now when I click on edit link of any organisation record it should display name and acc no of the organisation whose edit link I have clicked.I am not able to do that. Means how to pass the id of the record from one page to another when i click the on edit link of that record

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to retrieve all Organisation records via controller. You can find solution of it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_custom_list_controller.htm)
Next thing is to override action. You can use apex:commandLink and in the action return Pagereference to other page. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm) examples of the commandLink implementation.

Comment: rather  than including links only (since, they might change in the future) try including minimal code samples to answer. thanks!